# Is a Preprocessed C/C++ file machine-specific?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

Say I am on a linux machine, and I run the following command:

```
cpp main.cpp > main_p.cpp
```

Where `main.cpp` is a c++/c file. Would I be able to take `main_p.cpp` and compile/execute it on any other machine? Or is this program compiler-specific?

**Edit 1:** `cpp` is the C preprocessor, as defined by the `cpp(1)` man page.

Comment: The preprocessed output may well contain content that is compiler or system specific.   Particularly if the source file includes standard headers, since standard headers are free to use non-standard, implementation-specific features of the toolchain (e.g. compiler-specific intrinsics supported by some compilers and not others) or target system (e.g. OS specific APIs).   The C and C++ standards also only specify how an implementation as a whole behaves - they don't prevent (say) the preprocessor communicating with later phases of translation using some non-standard syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preprocessor output is very much system specific, particularly if standard header files are involved.

The standard header files in particular have a lot of system specific things in there as they are considered part of the implementation and as such can have a lot of implementation specific things.

For example, the following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When passed through the preprocessor on CentOS 7 results in an 843 line file.  The first few lines look like this:

```
# 1 "x1.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "x1.c"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 1 3 4
# 27 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/features.h" 1 3 4
# 375 "/usr/include/features.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h" 1 3 4
# 392 "/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/bits/wordsize.h" 1 3 4
# 393 "/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h" 2 3 4
# 376 "/usr/include/features.h" 2 3 4
# 399 "/usr/include/features.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h" 1 3 4
# 10 "/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/gnu/stubs-64.h" 1 3 4
# 11 "/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h" 2 3 4
# 400 "/usr/include/features.h" 2 3 4
# 28 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 2 3 4
```

If I take this resulting file and attempt to compile it using the `cl` command in Visual Studio a long list of errors are generated.

Taking the original source file and running it through the Visual Studio preprocessor has output that starts like this:

```
#line 1 "x1.c"
#line 1 "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.10240.0\\ucrt\\stdio.h"







#pragma once


#line 1 "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.10240.0\\ucrt\\corecrt.h"







#pragma once

#line 1 "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\INCLUDE\\vcruntime.h"
```

As you can see the output is very different.  Both compilers have different ways of denoting which source code line corresponds to a given line in the preprocessor output.  And that's just one example of the differences.